# unable to create a workspace in perforce

Tags: version-control, versioning, perforce

When I am trying to create a workspace view using perforce visual client, it pops up with an error,

```
Unable to create a workspace named '<folder name>

Error in client specification.

`ClientFilter` Validation failed:
==================================================
client view too loose!!!
each client should include one project only
==================================================
```

I am very new to P4V and I am not able to figure the error out. How do I resolve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not know this error message, but it might help if you paste the complete client form with that you tried to create a client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error from Perforce itself - it's coming from a trigger put in place by your Perforce administrators.  You should contact them to determine what to do about this.

Comment: Yes, I think so. But, when I tried to create/update workspace looking into other workspaces in the network, I was able to create or copy that workspace into my workspace.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that your administrators have a trigger that looks to see if you're mapping something like

//depot/... //clientname/...

Rather than something more specific like:

//depot/project1/... //clientname/project1/...